# Delayed API calls on back-end for PHP web site

Tags: php, mysql, database, delay

I have some api that can be called 5 times in second. And I have some web site with page that invokes api calls.
Is there a way of dealing with delaying api calls for users of site without any background worker that will invoke that api later(when some appropriate time between calls passes).
In my head it looks something like this: user invokes api call on site, this event added to database (with key like end_time=curr_time+120ms) and php sleep for 120ms and removes that database entry.
Then, when another user invokes api call using site, php script will get `end_time` of last database entry(if it still exists) as `last_end_time`, add new database entry with `end_time` equal to `last_end_time + 120ms` and sleep for that amount of time (`last_end_time + 120ms`), and so on for other users.
Is that strategy good?

Comment: What happens if you get many visitors at one single time? Will all their calls be delayed 120ms? Then you're basically just moved the problem 120ms into the future. What API is it? Is it user specific data?

Comment: Yes, seems to be so. It's https://www.blocktrail.com/api/docs#rate_limits. I need to create wallet for each user while registration.

Comment: If you hit that limit, you should upgrade your account for that service instead, because queuing up the calls won't work if you constantly hit the limit. You will need to add all calls in sequence, which means that eventually, when depends on the amount of traffic, some people might need to wait for hours or even longer...

Comment: Maybe there is some common practice for using public APIs with limitations? The limits, as I see is, 5 users per second, how can I track that on back-end side?

Comment: If the goal is just to keep the API request lag from slowing down the user's experience, then you could put the necessary data in a database table, with a column "Processed" set to 0 (FALSE). Set up an automated process through crontab so that the API interactions happen in the background. Crontab can be set to run every minute, and when it runs, have it process everything that has not been processed, then set "Processed" to 1 (TRUE). Once a day have other cron job that cleans the table, but leave the processed rows there for a while so you can debug.

Comment: Actually this is a good solution. I looked it up and found that many hosting providers have crontab support. Thanks!